# Modify/Remove user agent header for specific request in apache dispatcher

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, httpd.conf

I have a request to https://www.example.com/some.jsp?params with user agent as iphone. What I want to do is either remove the user agent header or replace it for this particular request. How can I achieve this by modifying dispatcher files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did eventually:

```
# Set variable to grep the request URL
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)(some\.jsp)(.*)$ replace_user_agent
# Set user agent
RequestHeader set User-Agent "Some user agent value" env=replace_user_agent
```

Or if you want to suppressed user agent, definitely not a good idea

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)(some\.jsp)(.*)$ delete_user_agent
RequestHeader unset User-Agent env=delete_user_agent
```